# React Native issue on vscode

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sdk, react-vis-network, android-reactivelocation

```
Opening on Android...
Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. Default install location not found: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk. 
Use ANDROID_HOME to set the Android SDK location.
Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. Default install location not found: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk. 
Use ANDROID_HOME to set the Android SDK location.
Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
```

I want to open this react application in my Android phone it also shows an error

- uncaught error java.net.connectexception failed to connect to
- so any one please help me to solve this issue

Comment: you can check setup - https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?guide=native&platform=android

Comment: its a environment issue you just need to set react native environment. Here is the link where you can check that https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup